# Search for sentence that may containing different words in Python

Tags: python, regex, search, sentence

In python, I have a string sentence as follows:

```
Change setting to value 50.
```

I essentially want to search for the sentence in a list of strings and extract the "setting" and "50" values, as they may be different.

I'm not terribly great with regular expressions, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your input data? what is the expected result?

Comment: It will always be that sentence, but written multiple times in a file, on new lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
"Change (.*?) to value (.*?)\."
```

https://regex101.com/r/gG5sK3/2

Where the first and the second group are your desired values!